# Как запретить на android удалять/очищать телефону/пользователю базу данных?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-sqlite

У меня в приложении есть база данных sqlite.

Пользователь может зайти в настройки своего телефона->приложения->моё приложение
И там можно очистить кэш, это не страшно, но можно и отчистить данные приложения, в том числе и базу данных.
Как сделать так, чтобы при очистке не удалялась база данных?

Comment: в этом же и смысл очистки, разве нет?

Comment: А если там очень важная информация, для нормальной работы приложения? 
Или заметки пользователя, и пользователь просто не осознаёт, что удаляет ВСЕ данные, не только КЭШ или временные данные.

Comment: я сразу скажу, я в android не понимню ничего, потоу просто предположу, что может быть БД и важные данные не должны лежать в папке с кешем?

Comment: Создаю полностью офлайновое приложение. В базе данных хранятся данные пользователя, которые он нагенерил. Он если захочет, может всё своё удалить в приложении, и хочется его защитить от самого себя, если он будет очищать кэш в настройках, чтобы он случайно не удалил ВСЁ.  @tym32167

Comment: Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20674059/312041) пишут, что есть разные варианты очистки данных, может это вам чем то поможет.

Comment: Спасибо! Этого ответа достаточно! @tym32167

Comment: На здоровье! Если сможете - запостите ответ, думаю это было бы полезно сообществу.

Answer (score 2):

Подробный ответ находится [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673862/prevent-deletion-of-database-or-shared-preference-on-clear-app/20674059#20674059). Спасибо @tym32167.

Стоит отметить, что в Android существует три типа очистки данных, над которыми ваше приложение не имеет контроля:

- Очистить данные
- Очистить кеш
- Очистить настройки по умолчанию

'Очистить данные' очистит все в рабочем каталоге приложения. Это включает в себя любые общие настройки, базы данных и файлы, сохраненные приложением, которые находятся в каталоге приложения. Это также очистит кэш приложения.

Очистить кэш. У приложения есть доступ к каталогу кеша, в который можно сохранять файлы, в основном для целей кэширования, таких как сгенерированные изображения или временные файлы.

Из этого следует, что единственная возможность сохранить данные, это делать бэкап вне приложения.

Comment: Есть ещё вариант: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7424193 - назначить собственную активность на кнопку очистки данных и самому реализовать эту очистку как угодно.

Answer (score 1):

Android предоставляет autobackup данных объёмом до 25М бесплатно на каждое прилажение.
Autobackup для базы данных sqlite включен автоматически.
Бэкап будет происходить в следующих случаяx:

1. Пользователь включил резервное копирование на устройстве. В Android 9 этот параметр находится в разделе «Настройки» > «Система» > «Резервное копирование» .
2. С момента последнего резервного копирования прошло не менее 24 часов.
3. Устройство не используется.
4. Устройство подключено к сети Wi-Fi (если пользователь устройства не включил резервное копирование мобильных данных).

Подробнее можно посмотреть на официальном [сайте](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup).